# JS RegExp Start at the second occurrence of <h2> tag and include everything after it

Tags: javascript, regex, string, tags

Using a regular expression (Javascript) I need to find the second `<h2>` tag in the article and return everything after it including the second `<h2>` tag.

I have an article that I need to break into three parts. I've got the first two parts and the third part of the article is what I describe above.

The 'markers' are the opening `<h2>` tags, meaning that the first part of my article starts at the very beginning of the string and stops just before the first `<h2>` tag, excluding it.

The second part includes the first `<h2>` tag and includes everything after it just before the second `<h2>` tag.

Now I need a regEx that finds the second `<h2>` tag, includes the tag and everything after it until the end of the string.

Here's what I've got so far:

The article structure:

```
<p>Here's the first paragraph</p>
<p>Here's the second one</p>
<p>Here's the third one</p>
<a>A link maybe</a>

<h2>Here's the first H2 tag</h2>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<a>A link maybe</a>
<img An image/>
<p>Another paragraph</p>

<h2>Here's the second H2 tag</h2>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<a>A link maybe</a>
<img An image/>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

The regular expression that returns the first three `<p></p>`s and the `<a></a>` and excludes the first `<h2>` is:

```
const firstBreak = /.+?(?=\<h2>)/im;
this.articleBody.match(firstBreak)[0]
```

The second regular expression returns the first `<h2>` and everything after it up until the second `<h2>`, excluding the second `<h2>`:

```
const secondBreak = /.+?(?=\<h2>)/gim;
this.articleBodyMiddle = this.articleBody.match(secondBreak)[1];
```

The third regular expression is where I'm stumped. This one is including the first `<h2>`, everything after it and the second `<h2>` and everything after it:

```
const thirdBreak = /(\<h2>?.*)/gi;
this.articleBodyBottom = this.articleBody.match(thirdBreak)[0];
```

I just need this last one to start at the second `<h2>` and include everything after it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: using regex to parse XML/HTML hardly ever works well...it's just not what regex is designed to do. You might consider using the [browser's built-in DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML), and then getting what you want with xpath or querySelectorAll or something.

Comment: Hi @David784, thanks for your comment. I know this is one of those rare cases in which I actually need to insert that content into different `divs` and additionally insert components between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be it will help:

```js
var str = `<p>Here's the first paragraph</p>
<p>Here's the second one</p>
<p>Here's the third one</p>
<a>A link maybe</a>

<h2>Here's the first H2 tag</h2>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<a>A link maybe</a>
<img An image/>
<p>Another paragraph</p>

<h2>Here's the second H2 tag</h2>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<a>A link maybe</a>
<img An image/>
<p>Another paragraph</p>`;

var result = str.match(/^[^]*?<h2>[^]*?(<h2>[^]*?)$/);
console.log(result[1]);
```

Explanation:

- `^` Start of the string.
- `[^]*?<h2>` match any thing until the first `<h2>`
- Second `[^]*?` match anything between the first and the second `<h2>`
- `(<h2>[^]*?)$` capture the second `<h2>` and everything after it.

Comment: @Cuong Le Ngoc Thank you very much! This worked like a charm!! I was really stumped. Thanks for the detailed explanation as well!